# How to replace the text in a file without searching the line by line using python?

Tags: python, file, replace

Example:

file1.txt contains 1000 lines of text, without search them line by line I need to replace them

```
aaaa bbbbb cccc
asdfd raj ccc
ksdhfkj kjhkjh kjhkjh
raj
```

Needs to be replaces **raj** as **sathish**

```
aaaa bbbbb cccc
asdfd sathish ccc
ksdhfkj kjhkjh kjhkjh
sathish
```

Is it possible to replace without search them line by line

Comment: I don't think so, you must read line by line if you wanna know its content. Or in any case, that's what your program would do

Comment: If your question is "Do I need to write a python `for` loop, the answer is no. But ultimately any call to a library function (using regex for example) will loop through line by line under the hood. (How could it do it without?)

Comment: Do you already know the position of the text you need to replace?  For example, is it always the last line?  Is it a specific byte offset?  If you don't know which position in the file then how else could you find it without searching?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
with open("textfile","r") as fi, open("outfile","w") as fo:
    fo.write(fi.read().replace("raj","sathish"))
```

Comment: There is no need to load the entire file into RAM really